# Gdal_translate raster from *.ecw to have arguement [-of GeoTiff] but saving the output as *.jpg

Tags: raster, gdal-translate

I am saving a raster from Qgis using gdal_translate lib. 
I put in the argument "-of GeoTiff" but the output has been defined as suffix = *.jpg

It does not throw any errors.. Is the final result a band-layered hybrid of a compressed image?

Comment: Explain with more details of add a screen capture about where and how you define the name of the output file. At least GDAL does not set extensions automatically and if you tell it to save GeoTIFF file as my_tif_image.jpg it does just that.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the output format to GeoTIFF and the file extension to JPG will not result in a hybrid GeoTIFF-JPEG file format. As can be seen in the [GeoTIFF spec on gdal.org](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html), the compression algorithm for the TIFF can be explicitly set using the creation option `COMPRESS`.